# turtlebot_node/TurtlebotSensorState.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I write my code use bumper sensor. But when I include library TurtlebotSensorState and catkin_make has error
/home/mai/catkin_ws/src/second/src/bump.cpp:9:49: fatal error: turtlebot_node/TurtlebotSensorState.h: No such file or directory
#include <turtlebot_node/TurtlebotSensorState.h>
^
How can I fix this error? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198325/turtlebot_node/turtlebotsensorstate.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Mai](https://answers.ros.org/users/20937/mai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TurtlebotSensorState is a ROS message type defined in the "turtlebot_node" package. If you get an "No such file or directory" error that likely means you haven´t properly specified the "turtlebot_node" dependency in the package you are working on. See [Dependency Management here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/conceptual_overview#Dependency_Management).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mai](https://answers.ros.org/users/20937/mai/) on 2014-12-07**:
Thanks Stefan Kohlbrecher. I add <build_depend>turtlebot_node</build_depend> and <run_depend> turtlebot_node</run_depend> in package.xml file but still error. I use Ubuntu 14.04 and ros indigo. How I fix this error. It take me 2 week. I am worry more. Thanks a lot for your help

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-12-10**:
You have to also adjust settings in the CMakeLists.txt, see the link I posted.